# Macro Find Last Row and Add Data

Tags: vba, excel

Each week I pull data for a series of items and generate a pivot table. Some weeks, no data exists for one or more of these items. When this is the case, that item won't appear on the report.

To avoid manually checking that no items have been accidentally excluded from the pivot table, I want to manually add "dummy" items to the data used in the pivot table.

I am pretty confident I can identify which dummy items to add by using COUNTIF between the master item sheet and the raw data. My challenge is that the number of rows in the pivot table varies week to week, so I need to 1) identify the last row of the raw data report, and 2) insert dummy rows below the last line.

Can anyone suggest a strategy using the example below?

**Items in Data**

```
AAA    
BBB    
DDD    
FFF
```

**Items Not in Data to Manually Insert**

```
CCC    
EEE
```

I am not getting any errors, but this isn't working.

```
Sub DUMMY_ITEMS()
'
' DUMMY_ITEMS Macro
Sheets("Operations").Select
Range("H2:V73").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Raw Data").Select
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are [finding the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920), check out the link. Adding data is not that hard.

Comment: So I'm not getting any errors, but this isn't working. Any help is really appreciated!

'Sub DUMMY_ITEMS()
'
' DUMMY_ITEMS Macro
    Sheets("Operations").Select
    Range("H2:V73").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub'

@l42; @tackgnol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your code in the comment here is the fixed version:

```
Sub DUMMY_ITEMS()

Dim operationsSheet As Worksheet
Dim rawDataSheet As Worksheet
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set operationsSheet = Sheets("Operations")
Set rawDataSheet = Sheets("Raw Data")

operationsSheet.Range("H2:V73").Copy

With rawDataSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
rawDataSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

I would however highly recommend you look into the Offset solution below to have a dynamic pivot data source.

On top of all that there is a neat trick to always keep your pivot table up to speed: 
Create a named range of a name *rData*

```
=OFFSET($A$1;;;COUNTA(A:A);COUNTA(1:1))
```

Where A1 is the begging of your PivotTable, COUNTA(A:A) counts the amount of rows it needs to extend the range to (pick any column that is filled in for all records), and COUNTA(1:1) counts the amount of headers. 
Put rData as pivot source. rData will extend any time you add a row or column. No macros needed.

I usually assign the full table to a data range

```
Set currentData = ActiveWorksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

Where Range("A1") is the beggining of the dataset

```
with currentData

   lastRow = .rows(.rows.count).row

end with
```

May not be the most optimal way to do it but works for me
Then you can thing underneath using

```
ActiveWorksheet.Cells(lastRow+1,1).Value = "CCC"
ActiveWorksheet.Cells(lastRow+2,1).Value = "EEE"
```

Or you can use offset

```
   Set rangeToFill = ActiveWorksheet.Cells(lastRow,1)
   rangeToFill.offset(1,0).value ="CCC"
   rangeToFill.offset(2,0).value ="EEE"
```

Hope this is of some help.